# Quantum Temperature?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I was thinking if temperature is proportional to the rate at which energy is transferred then does it exist on a quantum as well as a classical scale? If so what is it proportional to exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing temperature with heat. Remember the first law of thermodynamics, $\Delta U = Q + W$, where $\Delta U$ is a the change in internal energy, $Q$ is the heat transferred, and $W$ is the work done (Some books write the 1st law as $\Delta U = Q - W$, but it all comes down to whether you define work as what you do, or what the gas, or other material, does. However either equation will work for what I want to say).

It is $\Delta U$, that is proportional to temperature. For an ideal gas its something like $\Delta U = n C_v \Delta T$, where $n$ is the number of mols, $C_v$ is the heat capacity per mol, and $\Delta T$ is the change in temperature (again the formulas are slight different in different books). So what the first law tells you is that a **change in temperature is equal to the heat and work that was done.**  So it is not temperature that is "proportional to the rate at which energy is transferred", but rather the change in temperature.

**As far as what temperature really is, it is essentially an average of the velocities of the particles in your gas**. There is no real need to distinguish between classical temperature and quantum temperature. The difference in a classical and quantum picture of temperature is again more related to $\Delta U$ than it is to temperature itself. Without using quantum you cannot explain the $C_v$ of certain gases.